# Grub loading error 21

Tags: centos6, boot, grub

I have a 2-disk software RAID CentOS 6 system that I just installed. When I boot from the disk I get "Error 21" from GRUB. I have run this command on sda and sdb, after booting from the rescue DVD image:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 | xxd
```

I do see GRUB on both drives. I even ran this command for sda and sdb:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

fdisk -l does show sda and sdb as my devices.

So, I believe GRUB is on both disks and that I've got the right device names but when I tell the installer to boot from the local disk I get that error.

When I chroot to /mnt/sysimage everything looks fine.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

**Update on Nov. 8, 2016 to provide more info.**

[image]

fdisk -l
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please print your filesystem and RAID layout? It's nearly impossible to answer this with any precision without more data. Specifically, I'm not certain what kind of software RAID you're using (or if it's a controller), what filesystems you're using for things, and I would like to see a copy of your menu.lst file.

Comment: I've added a bunch of details. Please tell me what more you'd like to see. Thanks!